# Angular 5 - Can't bind to 'ngFormOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, angular5

We just recently updated our application Angular version to `v5` and as part of new update Forms support `ngFormOptions` to configure the validations for `form elements` on certain events. Below is what we have done:

```
<form class="example-form" autocomplete="off" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn:'submit'}" [formGroup]="testform">

</form>
```

But it's throwing below error

> **Can't bind to 'ngFormOptions' since it isn't a known property of
>   'form'**

Below the dependencies for the application after update.

***package.json***

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-accordion": "0.0.15",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.3",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2"
}
```

What else are we missing here? Why we still get this error even after the proper update?

Comment: Update the version to angular 5 
[**refer this Change log**]( https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-pentagonal-donut-2017-11-01) also this should be inside the form element such as `input` and not the `form` tag

Comment: @Aravind this can be specified in `form` tag as you can see **[from here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-forms-update-9587c3735cd3)**

Comment: Please read change log `add updateOn and ngFormOptions to NgForm ` I see `[formGroup]="testform"` in your form

Comment: @GuruprasadRao my bad, thank you :) might be the version update

Comment: Well, turns out this -> `this.testform = new FormGroup({
     //controls definition
    }, {updateOn: 'submit'});` works well..

Comment: FYI, `ngForm`s selector is `selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ngForm,[ngForm]'` (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L67). Thus, using `formGroup` directive on form will make this form as NOT `ngForm` and `ngFormOptions` will have no affect in this case

Comment: @Andriy Yes got it.. Thank you so much for information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Andriy mentioned in his comments

> `ngForms` selector is `selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ngForm,[ngForm]'`  - **[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L67)** . Thus, using `formGroup` directive on `form` will make this `form` as **NOT** `ngForm` and `ngFormOptions` will have no affect in this case.

Alternatively, we can use the said options in `component file as below:

```
this.testform = new FormGroup({
      testcontrol: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
}, {updateOn: 'submit'});
```